# How do you read a txt file (from SQLCMD) into Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlcmd

I've Google searched but haven't found a way to parse SQL txt file outputs and import as Pandas DataFrame.  I have, within the cmd line:

```
sqlcmd -S server_name -E -Q "select top 10 * from table_name" -o "test.txt"
```

This produces a text file, which isn't exactly the best format, since it has dashed lines and a comment saying (10 rows affected), but whatever.

Now, I do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep = ' ')
```

And it produces an error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10006 fields in line 3, saw 14963
```

Anyone know how to parse a SQL test file within Python?

Thanks!

Edit:  This would be the first column in the txt file:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample how the text file looks?

Comment: I added the first column

Comment: This looks more like fixed width file, you can use [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns) for this

Comment: yeah that gets really close to the result, thanks!  ijust have to drop the last row and first row!

Comment: Why not query the database directly from python? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: Because that's slow.  Takes me 30min to 1hour to run one query using that while it takes me 7 minutes to run through sqlcmd

Answer (score 0):

Add error handeling to the read_csv:

```
df_test = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep = ' ', errors='coerce')
```